# How to display all instances of a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my web application the user can select certain instances of an entity. For instance on the class `BubbleGum`, now the user can select certain instances of `BubbleGum` by adressing their identifier:

```
gums/details?show=3532667
```

Now, in addition I also want to make it possible to display all `BubbleGums`. For this I have introduced the convention of using `*` to identify all

```
gums/details?show=*
```

This works nice so far, but often I have to add a bit code to process the `*` selection. Is there a nice way to represent an **all-instances** object in Ruby and/or Rails?

I have thought of using simply a dedicated symbol, constants, or an actual object of the class `BubbleGum` that represents all the other bubble gums.

Comment: How about `BubbleGum.all`? Iterate over them with `BubbleGum.all.each...`

Comment: I agree. What about the controller code, check if a `*` was used and then make the call? I hope to find a solution which is not as timid, so I can avoid the whole if clause.

Comment: The "normal" way to do this would be to just have another route that does a list (index) of everything rather than a show. What is motivating the `*` approach? But yes, in your controller for the `show` you'd look for `params[:show]` value of `*`. Can you show your controller code for your `details`? That would help. (Having a parameter called "show" is making this conversation a little confusing... ;)).

Comment: @mbratch Ah okay. No, you are right on spot. I could post some code, but it's as you have stated it. The motivation is, that I have a dropdown menu on the details page which lists all the gums, and there is also an entry 'All', so instead of adding a new route I thought I could reuse the old one, but maybe you are right and I should create a  separate route for that.

Comment: See @Bot answer. You just need the common `index` route. If they select "All" you just go to the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display all the entities in a rails application generally we use a **index** page.

bubble_gums_controller.rb

```
def index
  @bubble_gums = BubbleGum.all
end
```

views/bubble_gums/index.html.erb

```
<% @bubble_gums.each do |bubble_gum| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= bubble_gum.name %></td>
    <td><%= bubble_gum.price %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Refer this for further details.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-posts

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use the query string param show.
So, you can try in your gums controller:

```
def details
    if params[:show] == "*"
        @bubble_gums = BubbleGum.all 
        # ...
    elsif params[:show]
        @bubble_gum = BubbleGum.find(params[:show]) 
        # ...
    else 
        render :status => 404
    end
end
```